# Free alternative to loggly

Tags: .net, azure, loggly

I would like find free alternative for loggly for write my logs with application.
Maybe there are open source alternative or free but he need deployment to my VM (Azure).

Comment: With some configuration you can use Sentry for general logging:
https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/12/monitoring-the-monitor.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are ready to setup your own server, you can use

- [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)
- [logstash](http://logstash.net/)
- [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/)

For me the splunk seems the easiest to setup.

If you don't want to setup your server, you need to use free plans in loggly-like services. That usually means maximum monthly limit you can send there and short retention (for how long your data will be stored)

- [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) (max 200MB/day, 7 days retention)
- [LogEntries](https://logentries.com/) (5GB/month, 7 days retention)
- [PaperTrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) (100MB/month, 2 days retention)

Our team have chosen LogEntries

Comment: None of them are free. All seem determined to get you to sign up and then make you pay something.

Comment: @csharpforevermore Logentries is free, up to 5 GB/month.

Comment: Logentries doesn't have a free plan anymore